# How do you replace a capture group with replaceAll() whilst returning the whole (modified) string?

Tags: java, talend

I'm having trouble using the replaceAll() function correctly. My aim is to read a file as a string object and then make various replacements to this string. In fact, my string object is an XML document which I've converted to string to allow me to make various modifications to it. This is a brute-force approach as  I have many XML files with various schemas and therefore my solution is to treat each file as a string object and then perform various find/replace operations on that string. I believe this approach is technically suitable to the problem I have to resolve.

The tool I'm actually using is Talend but this is all Java behind the scenes and my code is very much a standard java expression. Here's what I've done so far:

```
row1.content.replaceAll("<application (uuid)", "foo")
```

row1.content is my string object which contains the XML. My match expression correctly works but it replaces the entire match with foo. My goal is to only replace uuid with foo rather than the whole string. I'm sure this is very common i.e. matching a string with a regex and then only replacing a subset of that string. However, in my case the entire string is being replaced with foo. I'm aware you can refer to capture groups using $1, $2, etc. but I don't know how to replace only my capture group. I've tried the following syntax based on posts I've seen: $1foo, $1=foo, $1;foo. However, this just prints my entire string with uuidfoo, uuid=foo, uuid;foo, respectively.

As already mentioned, I need to return the following:

```
"<application foo"
```

This ensures my match string is retained and only the capture group is replaced. Also, because this is part of a much larger string, I also need to retain the rest of the string after this match has been replaced correctly. So my string object would look like:

```
"<application foo blah blah blah...."
```

I would then apply some other replace on a separate part of the string object (see my solution above) and then my final XML document would have all of the relevant string replacements made before I persist it. This whole solution is to allow me to mask certain parts of the file to meet data privacy requirements.

Comment: you can simply do `row1.content.replaceAll("<application (uuid)", "<application foo")`

Comment: Instead of regex and string manipulation why don't you use a proper xml parser?

Comment: I agree with @Eritrean, but if you insist on using regexp I'd do something like... `.replaceAll("(<application)\s+uuid(=['\"].*?['\"])?", "$1 foo")` as you should take account of the various whitespace options that are valid XML and that your uuid attribute might have a value assigned. if you want to preserve the value, then your replace string would be `$1 foo$2`. Be aware that this approach will only work if uuid is your first attribute and there is no rule that says the attributes have to be in any particular order.

Comment: @winter That approach won't work because the values within the string that my pattern matches is dynamic i.e. application will have other attributes with values I don't know about, therefore I can't apply a generic pattern to find my string and then hard-code a single string as part of a replacement value.

Comment: @Eritrean I always trying to implement this using the tools selected by my client. They use Talend which is a visual ETL tool that generates java code. Also, I figured that deserialising the file into a string and performing regex find/replace operations was a fairly reasonable approach? This is a fairly standard use case for regex and a large file. I will look into the parser option though as I need to find a solution asap. Thanks for the suggestion.